# Amount of time available for racking after fermentation is complete

Tags: fermentation, beer, racking

I have two things: five gallons of nut brown ale that is done fermenting, and the flu. I really don't feel up to racking so how many days can I safely delay it until I don't feel sick? My fermentation is at 14 days.

Comment: My fermentation period has been 14 days.

Comment: Please, edit new details into the question. This is not a forum, comments are not meant to carry anything that should be directly in the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depend on a lot of factors. If it was in fermenter only two weeks, one or two more should not hurt. For light beers, under 6% ABV, I never kept them over a month. But I do have few fermenters 3 or 4 weeks old now, waiting to be bottled somewhere next week. Oldest is strongest, of course.

For big beers, it was few months between pitch and bottling, and dang, it is delicious.

Anyway, just do not open it. Do not let air into it. Do not agitate. And if your initial plans were right, week more usually can't hurt.

Answer (score 3):

I just finished a nut brown: OG:51 FG:10. Left it on the primary yeast cake for three weeks and it turned out great. Lots of people are suggesting no secondary these days, and a little longer in the primary.

So, in answer to your question: let it rest while you rest. It'll be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you fermenting in plastic or glass?  Anything I ferment longer than a couple weeks or so goes in glass carboy.  Lighter pales and wheats with simple fermentation go into the plastic brew buckets.

I have a Tart Cherry Bourbon IPA aging on bourbon soaked Oak cubes and tart cherries currently in a carboy.  I would not do this in a plastic bucket.

If its in plastic, I would be more cautious.